# Laravel Eloquent Relationship hasMany hasOne

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I am trying to get my head around Laravel's relationships but having difficulty with the last part of what I'm trying to achieve.

My tables are like so:

**pagetemplates**

```
id
```

**pages**

```
id
pagetemplate_id
```

**pagetemplate_blocks**

```
id
pagetemplate_id
```

**pagetemplateblocks_content**

```
id
page_id
page_template_block_id
```

So when loading a page out of the DB I need to get it with pagetemplates, with it's blocks and with the content.

Here's my code so far:

**Page.php**

```
public function pageTemplate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('PageTemplate', 'pagetemplate_id')->with('blocks');
}

public function pagetemplateblockcontent()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('PageTemplateBlockContent', 'pagetemplateblocks_content', 'page_id', 'page_template_block_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function pagecontent()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PageTemplateBlockContent', 'page_id')->with('pagetemplateblock');
}
```

**PageTemplate.php**

```
public function page()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Page', 'pagetemplate_id');
}    

public function blocks() {
    return $this->hasMany('PageTemplateBlock', 'pagetemplate_id')->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->with('blockcontent');
}
```

**PageTemplateBlock.php**

```
public function pagetemplate() {
    return $this->belongsTo('PageTemplate', 'pagetemplate_id');
}

public function blockcontent() {
    return return $this->hasOne('PageTemplateBlockContent');
}
```

**PageTemplateBlockContent.php**

```
public function pagetemplateblock()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('PageTemplateBlock', 'page_template_block_id');
}
```

However, the issue is with the `content`, if I try this it returns one instance of PageTemplateBlockContent, which is the same for all of the pages. Although there should be a different PageTemplateBlockContent for each Page. I'm not sure how to get around this, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED**

My Controller calls

```
$this->pageRepo->where('id', $id)->with('pageTemplate');
```

"pageTemplate" returns the following:

```
return $this->belongsTo('PageTemplate', 'pagetemplate_id')->with('blocks');
```

"blocks" returns the following:

```
return $this->hasMany('PageTemplateBlock', 'pagetemplate_id')->orderBy('sort_order', 'asc')->with('blockcontent');
```

"blockcontent" returns the following:

```
return $this->hasOne('PageTemplateBlockContent');
```

So this means it's never hitting the "pagetemplateblockcontent" which Joost suggested creating.

Comment: Whats your query/way of getting the data out?

Comment: I'm using `$this->pageRepo->where('id', $id)->with('pageTemplate');`

Comment: what is with `$this->pageRepo` please add the full method to your question

Comment: It's not a method, it instantiates an eloquent repository so that I have access to the eloquent methods (where, with, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public function pagetemplateblockcontent()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('PageTemplateBlockContent', 'pagetemplateblocks_content', 'page_id', 'page_template_block_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

to

```
public function pagetemplateblockcontent()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('PageTemplateBlockContent', 'pagetemplateblockscontent_page', 'page_id', 'page_template_block_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and create an table page_pagetemplateblockcontent with two primary keys like so.

```
$table->integer("page_id")->unsigned();
$table->integer("page_template_block_id")->unsigned();

$table->primary(['page_id', 'page_template_block_id']);
```

Comment: The only thing (the part I'm getting confused about) is that a pagetemplateblock can have many pagetemplateblockcontent's, although this is related to a specific page as well as the pagetemplateblock. Does your example take this into consideration?

Comment: If you chain your page to pagetemplateblockcontent you only would get the relations linked with page so. yes if you mean that. Keep your code simple Page does not have to derectly link with pagetemplateblock or its content if your relations are set up correctly you sould get the ones only related to the current page.

Comment: I've just tried your method but I receive the following error:
`Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: Edited my awnser did you setted up your relations like that?

Comment: I've changed the models to reflect your changes Joost, and now I have this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pageTemplateBlocks()` although this method definitely exists in PageTemplate.php, any ideas? Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Also, one thing to bear in mind is that upon creating a new page, there won't be any records in the DB for the pagetemplateblockcontent, as this is adding upon editing the page using Laravel's sync() method.

Comment: Oh wait..... your belongsToMany relation is wrong... do you even have a pivot table for that?

Comment: Otherwize you cant use an many to many relation.. an many to many attaches for example page one to content one and page two can also have content one. try my new awnser and just use your old code

Comment: I've updated my question to help give an insight in to the flow of what's happening, as adding the pivot table hasn't fixed the issue.